# Printing from Windows Service / C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I saw in an earlier post/question that DevExpress' XtraReports was used successfully to do this.  Can anyone elaborate on this solution?  What I really want to do is just print received TIFF images using the service we are developing.  Don't need desktop interaction, just a way to grab a TIFF image and push it to the printer of our current choice.

Comment: can you please refer to the earlier post that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you have worked with Xtrareports this should help you. You need to use ReportPrintTool for this task.

```
        XtraReport1 rep = new XtraReport1();
        ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(rep);
        tool.Print(PrinterName);
```

Comment: And you can do this from a C#/.NET service ??